# What is happening when I declare a string as: char aString[SIZE*2+1];?

Tags: string

I am studying an example of a program the takes a user input, stores in a string then prints two occurrences of the corrosponding character in upper or lower case. For example, input ABCdef would print aabbccDDEEFF.

I'm a little bit confused about the way the new string is declared, can anybody help explain what is happening.

```
char string[MAX_STRING_SIZE+1];      // MAX_STRING_SIZE is defined as 500 and +1 is for the NULL char to terminate string 
char stringNew[MAX_STRING_SIZE*2+1]; // Here I do not understand *2+1
```

EDIT: Just after I posted this question I figured out the answer and realised it may not be useful to the stack overflow community but as the question had already been answered it would be rude to delete it.

In the event that an other member is interested in this specific question I have attempted to make it useful by editing the question title and summarising the answer.

As this program will print 2 occurrences of every character from the user input, the new string needs to be twice the size as the original string. By declaring the new string size with *2 you are simply multiplying the size by 2 thus doubling the size.

Very simple in hindsight, I hope this can be of use to somebody else.

Comment: You are allowed to post answer to your own question, but don't edit your own question to add the "answer". Questions are questions.

Comment: @user202729 My mistake, I will know in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No pointers are involved in that declaration. You're just declaring another array of `char`s that is twice the size of the first one + the extra byte that'll store `\0`.

It can't be a pointer because there are no identifiers between the square brackets. After the preprocessor will have done its job with the source file, that expression will actually become `char stringNew[500*2+1];`

Comment: I did realise this just after I had posted the question so I edited it, it seems obvious now but but just threw me a little as I've not seen it before. Thank you for explaining.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm sorry for posting such a short answer; I would've left a comment (which was more appropriate) but I don't have enough reputation to do that.

Comment: @brainplot Short answers are not a problem if they actually solves the problem. Comments are only for suggesting improvements (although in some cases people use it to explain why a question is a typo error and should be closed, effectively answer the question, although those are for off-topic questions, don't care)